# Eliminate html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a html string like

```
Lorem ipsum <a href='google.com'>google <span>rulz</span></a> not sum
```

I wanna delete all html tags, I mean I wanna delete all the html elements, so the string should transform to (in javascript)

```
Lorem ipsum not sum
```

I tried it matching (and replace) it ussing:

```
<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.+?<\/([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>
```

The problem is that I get

```
Lorem ipsum </a> not sum
```

I suposse the it happens because the regular expression replace "google rulz" but I would like it to replace the hole html tag.

Any idea?

Comment: Any reason you're not using an HTML parser?

Comment: Instead of removing the opening and closing tags in one regex, have you tried replacing *any* tag: `<.*?>`?  This way the opening and closing tags will get removed separately, and there's no need to worry about matching them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery to create a virtual element and get it's text contents, i.e.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
d = $('div');
d.html(text);
stripped = d.text();
</script>
```

Comment: thats is not in fact what i would use but I could use `<script type='text/javascript'>
d = $('div');
d.html(text);
d.children().remove();
stripped = d.text();
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [php.js strip_tags()](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving this text from an element you could get its `innerText` which will return the text with no html like so.

```
console.log(getElementById('someId').innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

`<[^>]*>` matches anything that *looks remotely like* a HTML tag. If this is not good enough, you should use a full fledged HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

try 
`var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi`